# BASH: while with -le doesn't work

Tags: bash, while-loop, conditional-statements

If i'm using -le with while i'm getting the following error:

```
line 172: [: : integer expression expected
```

what i'm doing wrong here?

my code:

```
while [ "$LOOP_EPISODE" -le "100" ]; do

        my code
        LOOP_EPISODE=$((LOOP_EPISODE+1))
done
```

Comment: In Bash, don't you think `while (( $LOOP_EPISODE < 100 ))` is more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
LOOP_EPISODE=0
```

before your while statement.